# React Class component covert to function component

Tags: reactjs, class, react-hooks, static

Problem is static variable.

class component use static variable like this.

```
// component.js
<ProgressWindow messageSet={ProgressWindow.MESSAGE_FOR_REPORT} />
 
// ProgressWindow.js
class ProgressWindow extends React.Component {
  static  MESSAGE_FOR_REPORT = 'report';
  static MESSAGE_FOR_SETTING = 'setting';
}
```

My mission is that static variable's convert to function component.

I need get messageSet value in new function ProgressWindow component.

How can i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
const ProgressWindow = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.MESSAGE_FOR_REPORT}</div>
    );
};

ProgressWindow.MESSAGE_FOR_REPORT = 'report';
ProgressWindow.MESSAGE_FOR_SETTING = 'setting';

export default ProgressWindow;
```

There is alternative static variable in Functional Component

```
ProgressWindow.MESSAGE_FOR_REPORT = 'report';
ProgressWindow.MESSAGE_FOR_SETTING = 'setting';
```

Comment: OMG. You are my hero!